# Horizontal positioning of caption in sidecap figure

Tags: spacing, captions, sidecap

I need to control the horizontal spacing between my figure and the related caption, which I am putting on the right of it by `sidecap`. How can I achieve it? Using `floatrow` instead of `sidecap`, is not an option for me due to some proprietary `documentclass` I need to work on which is not compatible with `floatrow`. I tried by setting `skip` in the `caption` package in the preamble, but it does not work apparently.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% Some basic caption settings 
\usepackage[style=base,skip=0pt]{caption}  %% `skip` here does not seem to have any effect 
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}
% caption on the top right
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{name}
\caption*{This is going to be a long caption, and I need to have it as much as possible within the figure space, so I want to control the horizontal space between figure and caption optimally...}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you thought about an own caption format?

Comment: @TeXnician Not really. Could you elaborate more on that? How could I do that? Is it the fastest solution? Perhaps using `minipage`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could individually style it with your own caption style. This has only one main disadvantage: If you use a `\parbox` as I would suggest you have a fixed width of the caption for each figure (which is not very practical unless you typeset the caption into the margin).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% Some basic caption settings 
\usepackage[style=base]{caption}  %% `skip` here does not seem to have any effect 
\DeclareCaptionFormat{side}{\hspace*{1cm}\parbox{4cm}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup{format=side,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period}
% caption on the top right
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}

\begin{document}
\begin{SCfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{name}
\caption*{This is going to be a long caption, and I need to have it as much as possible within the figure space, so I want to control the horizontal space between figure and caption optimally...}
\end{SCfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, in practice `SCfigure` has also  an additional optional [__relwidth__](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sidecap/sidecap.pdf) argument which somehow limits the max extension of the caption. Let me try it. My point is that there seems not to be a direct way to control this space. I was looking for something like `\sidecaptionvpos` but there is not an equivalent for `hpos` within the caption it seems...

Comment: Ok, it did the trick, although indeed, it is not the ideal solution, insofar as it requires every time manually changing `\parbox` or `\hspace*` values when the figure changes or is rescaled....

Comment: @maurizio I know, maybe there will be one with another solution in the future.